# can't pin process to the core that was re-enabled with online flag

Tags: linux, cpu, affinity

I wanted to disable one of the cores using Linux shell, so I used the command:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu63/online
```

It appeared in offline cores with `lscpu` and I could not set any thread on this core with `sched_setaffinity` method anymore. So it worked. However now I want to enable this core again with the command:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu63/online
```

In `lscpu` I see this core in online cores. However while trying to call `sched_setaffinity` in the same core it gives -1 as a result. Before disabling the core this method was working fine. also, I can not see this core with `lstopo`, it does not reappear in the NUMA anymore.

I am testing on skylake server with two NUMAs.

After reboot this core will show up of course but why is enabling command not working? or is there something else I need to do for it to work properly?

Comment: I am trying to use sched_setaffinity in my code, which does not work because re enabling core is not working properly apparently and the process does not see the core as online. Why is this not connected with programming?